# Problema con ahorcado en Python

Tags: python

estoy haciendo el juego del ahorcado en Python y tengo un incoveniente que no puedo solucionar. El problema es que aunque haya adivinado todas las letras, hasta que no escriba una letra que no esté en la palabra secreta no aparece el mensaje de que gané y no debería ocurrir eso.

Ejemplo de ejecución:

Enter a letter: a

You guessed a letter.

Enter a letter: d

You guessed a letter.

Enter a letter: i

You guessed a letter.

Enter a letter: n

You guessed a letter.

Enter a letter: ñ

You missed and lost a life.

You have 4 lifes left.

Enter a letter: f

You guessed a letter.

Enter a letter: l

You guessed a letter.

Enter a letter: i

This letter has already been entered. Enter another letter.

Enter a letter: n

This letter has already been entered. Enter another letter.

Enter a letter: p

You missed and lost a life. You have 3 lifes left.
Enter a letter: e

You guessed a letter.

**Enter a letter: m**

You won. The secret word is: Delfina.

**Código**:

```py
import random

words = ['Daniel', 'Cristian', 'Lucio', 'Alejandra', 'Delfina', 'Diana', 'Joshua', 'Pedro', 'Rick']
secret_word = random.choice(words)
secret_word_copy = set(secret_word.lower())
found_letters = set()
lives = 5

while lives > 0:
    letter = input('Enter a letter: ').lower()
        
    if len(letter) != 1 or not letter.isalpha():
        print('The value entered is invalid.')
    elif letter in found_letters:
        print('This letter has already been entered. Enter another letter.')
    elif letter in secret_word_copy:
        secret_word_copy.remove(letter)
        found_letters.add(letter)
        print('You guessed a letter.')
    elif len(secret_word) == len(found_letters):
        print(f'You won. The secret word is: {secret_word}.')
        break
    else:
        lives -= 1
        print(f'You missed and lost a life. You have {lives} lifes left.')
else:
    print(f'You lost. The secret word is: {secret_word}.')
```

Comment: puro problema de logica... si haces un seguimiento en papel, veras que al adivinar la ultima letra, no estas comprobando si la palabraesta completa... lo estas haciendo en la vuelta que sigue.. Ademas, como usas elif, el orden de las cosas es importante... si repetis una letra no va a salir que adivinaste la palabra, porque se va primero por ese if... Vos deberias comprobar si gano, cada vez que adivine una letra.. no en otros casos..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la condición de ganar está de última, entonces, alguna de las condiciones anteriores es verdadera y hace que se repita el bucle y no se pueda comprobar la condición de ganar.

Lo que podrias hacer es mover la condición de ganar al primer lugar, es decir, que tenga la sentencia if en vez de elif. Algo como esto:

```py
while lives > 0:    
    if len(set(secret_word.lower())) == len(found_letters):
        print(f'You won. The secret word is: {secret_word}.')
        break 

    letter = input('Enter a letter: ').lower()
        
    if len(letter) != 1 or not letter.isalpha():
        print('The value entered is invalid.')
    elif letter in found_letters:
        print('This letter has already been entered. Enter another letter.')
    ...
```

Otra cosa, la condición de ganar que tenias (len(secret_word) == len(found_letters)) nunca será verdadera, porque los Sets no almacenan datos duplicados. Por ejemplo, si la palabra secreta es 'Alejandra', len(secret_word) vale 10 y cuando se adivinen todas las letras len(found_letters) solo valdrá 7, porque 2 de las 'a' que contiene la palabra 'Alejandra' no se incluirán en el set, porque son valores repetidos.

Comment: Gracias, pude arreglarlo.

Comment: Si haces asi, estas obligando a que ingrese otra letra despues de que ingreso la ultima letra correcta. O sea, tu solucion no esta bien. La segunda parte de la explicacion, si es correcta.

Comment: @gbianchi Tenes razón. Ahí edite la respuesta para el OP. De este manera apenas inicie el bucle se comprobará si la condición de ganar es verdadera.